# update project classpath with ant after retrieving dependencies in ivy

Tags: ant, build, classpath, ivy, artifactory

that's a part of my build.xml

```
<property name="dir.ivy" value="${user.home}/.ivy2" description="Local Ivy Repository" />

<target name="retrieve" depends="clean,init">

    <!-- Resolve dependencies -->
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml"/>
    <ivy:retrieve type="jar" conf="${ivy.configuration}" pattern="${dir.ivy}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>

    <!-- Update classpath -->
    ???

</target>
```

After i downloaded the dependencies, defined in my ivy.xml, from artifactory or maven i would like to add them to my project classpath without adding them manually from Project - Configure Build Path... and without compiling my classes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found a solution, i used the [Apache IvyDE](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/) plugin for eclipse to update the project classpath.

Answer (score 1):

The [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task can be used create an ivy managed classpath.

For an example see:

- [How to avoid copying dependencies with Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609465/how-to-avoid-copying-dependencies-with-ivy/2611353#2611353)