# using ant manifest path entry building from path of the dependency jars

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib

My problem is , i have to build the manifest entry classpath from the path like

- C:\Users\rosansamuel.ivy2\cache\log4j\log4j\jars\log4j-1.2.14.jar

Can you please any one suggest some ideas?

Below code is , i am trying with propertyregex, but actually i can't able to get the jar names.

```
<for list="${ofsml.manifest.classpath.list}" delimiter=";" param="individual.path">
  <sequential>
    <property name="single.artifact.path" value="@{individual.path}"/>
    <echo message="single aritfact path name : ${single.artifact.path}"/>
    <path id="my.base.path">
      <pathelement path="${single.artifact.path}"/>
    </path>
    <property name="artifact.id.file" refid="my.base.path"/>
    <echo message=" artifact.id.file: ${artifact.id.file}"/>
    <propertyregex property="artifact.id" input="${artifact.id.file}" regexp=".*.jar" select="\1"/>
    <echo message="jar name : ${artifact.id}"/>
    <echo message="individual.path = @{individual.path}"/>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: Didn't understand what you're asking for, but it seems like you need to get the filename only from an absolute filepath ?! There's a <basename> task for that purpose. Also when using \1 your regexp should have a group, f.e. .+\\(.+jar) means \1 would catch log4j-1.2.14.jar from C:\Users\rosansamuel.ivy2\cache\log4j\log4j\jars\log4j-1.2.14.jar

Comment: Hi Mate, yes you are correct. my requirement is to extract the jar name alone from the path. But i am having the list of paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [manifestclasspath](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) task in ANT that can generate a list of relative filepaths from a fileset.

I also see that you're using ivy, so why not use its [retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) task to place your dependency jars in a local directory relative to the jar you are building. Otherwise your jar will be hard-coded to expect its dependencies to be an absolute path that works on your machine, but not very portable.

Here's an small snippet:

```
  <target name="build" depends="compile">
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${dist.dir}/lib/[artifact].[ext]"/>

    <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="${dist.jar}">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </manifestclasspath>

    <jar destfile="${dist.jar}" basedir="${build.dir}/classes">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${dist.main.class}"/>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/>
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>
```

For a more complete example, see:

- [How to avoid copying dependencies with Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609465/how-to-avoid-copying-dependencies-with-ivy/2611353#2611353)