# Keeping only the latest dependency snapshot using Ant and Ivy

Tags: ant, ivy, dependency-management, snapshot

I am using Ant to build my project and Ivy to resolve its dependencies. My project has a dependency which publishes snapshots to my internal Artifactory server.

If the dependency has released a new snapshot, and I do an `<ivy:retrieve />`, Ivy gets the new snapshot but keeps the previous snapshot around. So I have two versions of the dependency in my `lib` directory.

The dependency snapshots are named like `depproject-1.0.0+23.jar` where `23` is the build number. It is published at an address like http://artifactory.example.com/example-snapshots-local/com.example/depproject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/depproject-1.0.0+23.jar. This is not a Maven repository, and it is configured to store unique snapshots.

I am new to Ivy. Is this the expected behavior? How can I configure Ivy or Ant so that only the latest dependency snapshot is kept?

**ivysettings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-settings>
    <settings defaultResolver="main" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="main">
            <ibiblio
                name="artifactory-example-snapshots"
                m2compatible="false"
                root="http://artifactory.example.com/example-snapshots-local/"
                pattern="[organization]/[module]/1.0-SNAPSHOT/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
            <!-- more repos listed -->
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivy-settings>
```

**ivy.xml**

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.example" module="myproject" />
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.example" name="depproject" rev="latest.integration" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using jars in the lib directory to create a classpath, something like:

```
<path id="compile.path">
  <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

Your issue being multiple jars containing the same classes?

I think you have two options:

1. Use the ivy [cachepath](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task to manage the build classpaths
2. Purge the lib directory, using he [retrieve](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) task to repopulate with the latest jars

The first option may appear more complicated, but it is actually a very powerful way to use ivy. For an example see:

- [How to avoid copying dependencies with Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609465/how-to-avoid-copying-dependencies-with-ivy/2611353#2611353)