# getting error in ivy.xml throwing exception

Tags: ivy

I am getting the below exception upon ivy-configure tag , i have configured the ivy configure tag in my build-ivy.xml as shown below

my ivy.xml is at the below path..

```
/ops/ivy/ivy.xml
```

my ivy-settings.xml is at..

```
/ops/ivy/ivysettings.xml
```

and my ivy:configure entry in build.xml as shown below ...

```
<!-- Ivy -->
    <target name="prepare" description="Ivy setting load">
            <echo message="Saral in Prepare"/>
            <delete dir="${project_dependencies}"/>
            <mkdir dir="${project_dependencies}"/>
            <path id="classpath">
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="${ops.dir}/ivy/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </path>


            <ivy:configure file="${ops.dir}/ivy/ivysettings.xml" />
                    <ivy:retrieve  type="jar" pattern="${project_dependencies}/[artifact].[ext]"/>
            </target>
```

the error that i am getting is ...please advise where i need to configure ivy.xml

```
prepare:
     [echo] Saral in Prepare
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\DTSTOTALUPLOADED\Glacier\project_dependencies
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\DTSTOTALUPLOADED\Glacier\project_dependencies
[ivy:configure] :: Apache Ivy 2.3.0 - 20130110142753 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:configure] :: loading settings :: file = C:\DTSTOTALUPLOADED\Glacier\ops\ivy\ivysettings.xml
[ivy:retrieve] C:\DTSTOTALUPLOADED\Glacier\ivy\ivy.xml (The system cannot find the path specified) in file:/C:/DTSTOTALUPLOADED/Glacier/ivy/ivy.xml

BUILD FAILED
```

folks please advise on this..!

Answer (score 0):

Ivy is designed to manage a software projects dependencies, using an ivy file that is normally committed locally into the source code.

For a working example see:

- [How to avoid copying dependencies with Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609465/how-to-avoid-copying-dependencies-with-ivy/2611353#2611353)

## Additional info

### Location of ivy file

Typically the project files look something like the following:

```
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml        <-- Ivy file detailing project dependencies
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── myorg
                └── MyClass.java
```

### Cleanup targets

I would suggest moving build cleanup logic into a separate set of targets and additionally leverage the [cleancache](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cleancache.html) ivy task.

```
<target name="clean" description="Cleans up files created by build">
  <delete dir="build"/>
  <delete dir="lib"/>
</target>

<target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
  <ivy:cleancache/>
</target>
```

### Managing classpath

A more efficient way to manage the build classpath is to use the ivy [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task instead of [retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html).

This approach is especially powerful if you use ivy configurations, allowing you to control multiple classpaths.

### Bootstrapping ivy

I don't think the following code is redundant:

```
<path id="classpath">
  <fileset dir="lib">
    <include name="${ops.dir}/ivy/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>
```

Adding the ivy jar onto a project path after ANT is started would be too late. Check your *$ANT_HOME/lib* or *~/.ant/lib* directories. I'll bet the ivy jar is there already?