# Error with target in building by build.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ivy, antbuilder

I have opened  a project which has build.xml and ivy.xml in eclipse env.
after I applied Run As..>Ant Built by right click build.xml, I faced this error:

```
    BUILD FAILED
Target "retrieve" does not exist in the project "aaa". It is used from target "compile".
```

my build.xml file:

```
<project name="WOE" default="build">

    <!--<import file="../build/ivy-targets.xml"/>-->

    <property name="dir.base" location="."/>
    <!--<property name="dir.repos" location="${dir.base}/../repository/modules"/>-->
    <property name="dir.src" location="${dir.base}/src/java"/>
    <property name="dir.lib" location="${dir.base}/src/lib"/>
    <property name="dir.ivy.lib" location="${dir.base}/lib"/>
    <property name="dir.build" location="${dir.base}/build"/>
    <property name="dir.classes" location="${dir.build}/classes"/>
    <property name="module.jar" location="${dir.build}/WOEParse.jar"/>

    <property name="dir.doc" location="${dir.base}/doc"/>
    <property name="dir.javadoc" location="${dir.doc}/api"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${dir.lib}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${dir.ivy.lib}/default" includes="*.jar"/>
        <!--<pathelement path="${dir.repos}/edu.stanford/BaselineNLProcessor/521/jars/baseline-nlprocessor-2010-06-22-521.jar" />-->
    </path>

    <path id="run.classpath">
        <path refid="classpath"/>
        <pathelement location="${module.jar}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="clean" description="Deletes artifacts produced by build">
        <delete dir="${dir.build}"/>
        <delete dir="${dir.javadoc}"/>
        <delete dir="${dir.ivy.lib}"/>
    </target>

     <target name="compile" depends="retrieve" description="Compiles source code">
        <mkdir dir="${dir.classes}"/>
        <javac destdir="${dir.classes}"
               debug="true"
               target="1.6">
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
            <src path="${dir.src}"/>
        </javac>

    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="compile" description="Builds module JAR file">
        <jar jarfile="${module.jar}">
            <fileset dir="${dir.classes}" includes="**/*.class"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="build" description="Processes a simple example file">
        <java classname="edu.washington.cs.woe.WOEParse" fork="true" failonerror="true">
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx1G"/>
            <classpath refid="run.classpath"/>
            <arg line="-inFile ./light-config/data/testSentenceFile -cfDir ./light-config/"/>
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="javadoc" description="Builds javadoc html files for this source code">
        <mkdir dir="${dir.javadoc}"/>
        <javadoc classpathref="classpath" destdir="${dir.javadoc}" sourcepath="${dir.src}">
            <packageset dir="${dir.src}" defaultexcludes="yes">
            </packageset>
        </javadoc>
    </target>


</project>
```

The error is occurred in this part:

[image]

I changed it to

```
<target name="compile"  description="Compiles source code">
```

but it shows another error:

```
Buildfile: D:\eclipse workspace\WOE\build.xml
compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\eclipse workspace\WOE\build\classes
    [javac] D:\eclipse workspace\WOE\build.xml:38: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 42 source files to D:\eclipse workspace\WOE\build\classes

BUILD FAILED
D:\eclipse workspace\WOE\build.xml:38: D:\eclipse workspace\WOE\lib\default does not exist.

Total time: 328 milliseconds
```

What should I do?
Is there any problem with eclipse env?(I dont have any ant plugin or etc. in Eclipse env), if so, which plugin should I use in eclipse to maybe properly open such projects?

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Show us the build.xml

Comment: @greg-449: Ok. I did it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
 <target name="compile" depends="retrieve"
```

Either declare target with the name 'retrieve' or remove the dependency.

Comment: you mean I change it to:
<target name="compile" description="Compiles source code">

Or

<target name="retrieve" description="Compiles source code">

Doesn't have destructive effect in whole project?
I have no knowledge about targets!!

Answer (score 1):

Is this a build file created by copy-n-pasting from another build file?

## First issue

You have a compile target that depends on another non-existent target called "retrieve"

```
 <target name="compile" depends="retrieve" description="Compiles source code">
    <mkdir dir="${dir.classes}"/>
    <javac destdir="${dir.classes}"
           debug="true"
           target="1.6">
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        <src path="${dir.src}"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

When using ivy it's quite common to have a target that first resolves (downloading if necessary) 3rd party jar dependencies. This is necessary in order to compile your code.

## Second issue

Your second error is thrown by the following part of your build:

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${dir.lib}" includes="*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${dir.ivy.lib}/default" includes="*.jar"/>
    <!--<pathelement path="${dir.repos}/edu.stanford/BaselineNLProcessor/521/jars/baseline-nlprocessor-2010-06-22-521.jar" />-->
</path>
```

The code is expecting to find jars in the **${dir.ivy.lib}/default** directory. Presumably this happens as part of the missing retrieve task.

## Working example using ivy

Hope this helps.

- [How to avoid copying dependencies with Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609465/how-to-avoid-copying-dependencies-with-ivy/2611353#2611353)
- [Class not found with Ant, Ivy and JUnit - error in build.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml/15982144#15982144)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preference, check "Ignore all buildfile problems".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SiqM.png]