# How can I extract maven depencencies to use in an ant script?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, jar

I need import my project's dependencies with maven.

But, I also need to compile the project with an ant script.

Before using maven, I had a lib folder with the jars. But now the jars are in a folder of maven which can be in multiple locations.

This is my target and path:

```
<path id="classpath.compilar">
    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}" />
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="compilar" depends="limpiar">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <javac destdir="${classes.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}"
        classpathref="classpath.compilar" includeantruntime="false" />
</target>
```

I need to add these jars in the path, but I don't know how get it from maven.

Does anyone know how to do this? Any task to get a fileset with this jar files?

Comment: Not the same. I don't want convert ant project into maven project. I have a maven project whit a script ant. Maven project resolve the dependencies downloading needed jars in maven local repository, and I want use this jars in ant, to create a listset for a path.

Comment: In that case read the antrun plugin documentation. It describes how to access the Maven managed classpaths. (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html) another link explains how to use custom ANT tasks via plugin dependencies (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/customTasks.html)

Comment: But I don't want use ant target in maven. I want use maven dependencies in ant, without maven(only for download this dependencies). I do not know if I'm explaining well.

Comment: Your question was phrased in such a way that it appears you are using both Maven and ANT to compile your project... I would suggest checking out Apache ivy. It contains additional tasks for download dependencies from Maven. For example see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609465/how-to-avoid-copying-dependencies-with-ivy/2611353#2611353

Comment: And another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml/15982144#15982144

Comment: I do not speak English very well, and maybe I have not expressed myself correctly. It's a practice of university and I only can use ant for management, and maven to resolve dependencies. I can't use Ivy. Thanks for you help.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. Ivy is an ANT plugin that can download dependencies from Maven repositories. Try it and you'll discover how it works.