# ant - build jar with lib inside and in MANIFEST classpath

Tags: jar, ant, manifest, ivy

I have the following for building my jar currently:

```
 <jar jarfile="${bin.dir}/${name}.jar" basedir="${build.src.dir}">
            <zipfileset src="${bin.lib.dir}/dependencies-compact.jar"
                        excludes="META-INF/*.SF" />
  </jar>
```

But this makes everything jumbled inside the jar.  The plan now is inside the jar, there will be a folder called lib, and the MANIFEST.MF's classpath variable will be updated with the list of all the jars in lib folder.  How to achieve this on ant?

Answer (score 0):

The classpath in the Manifest refers to external jars, not classes that you have pulled inside your jar file.

The following is a sample of how I use ivy to put my jar's dependencies into an adjacent "lib" directory and then use the ANT [manifestclasspath](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) task to construct the string that goes into the jar manifest:

```
  <target name="build" depends="compile">
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${dist.dir}/lib/[artifact].[ext]"/>

    <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="${dist.jar}">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </manifestclasspath>

    <jar destfile="${dist.jar}" basedir="${build.dir}/classes">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${dist.main.class}"/>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/>
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>
```

For more detailed examples that include ivy files and unit tests see:

- [How to avoid copying dependencies with Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609465/how-to-avoid-copying-dependencies-with-ivy/2611353#2611353)
- [Class not found with Ant, Ivy and JUnit - error in build.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml/15982144#15982144)